# Mark literal as 32bit

Tags: int, long-integer, lotusscript

I have the following Lotus Script code

```
Dim MyVar As Long
MyVar = 327 * 100
MyVar = 328 * 100
```

The last line of this code throws an "Overflow" compiler error.

I guess this is because the product of two numeric literals of less than 16bit is returned as a 16 bit, and only then casted to a long.

In Java, I can write:

```
MyVar = 328L * 100
```

and the compiler knows that it should multiply a long. How can I achieve the same in Lotus Script?

Comment: maybe the notes help helps, https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/basic/LSAZ_SPECIAL_CHARACTERS.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
MyVar = 329& + 100&
```